# how to assign variable in module if I export it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to import file with `require` in another file. How would I set variable of imported file.

suppose 'sample.js'

```
var a = '';
var b = '';
export.funcA = function(){
}
export.funcB = function(){
}
export.funcC = function(){
//somewhere I am using a & b variable with dynamic values that need to be set run time.
}

//script.js
var sample = require('sample.js');
//Now before using function `funcC` I want to dynamically set values of variable a & b. 
so I can easily use `sample.funcC()`;
```

// I don't want to pass it using a parameter. because I am already assigning third to funcC so I can't set parameter.

Comment: How are you getting  your dynamic value and when you want to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export an object:

```
// sample.js
module.exports = {
  a: '',
  b: '',
  funcA: function funcA() {
  },
  funcB: function funcB() {
  },
  funcC: function funcC() {
    return this.a + this.c;
  }
};

// script.js
var sample = require('sample.js');
sample.a = 'foo';
sample.b = 'bar';
sample.funcC(); // => 'foobar';
```

Comment: Did it almost the same way.